# to_char of negative number round up becomes -0 instead of just 0

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to format the value to whole number (removing decimals) but when the value is a negative number less than 0, it's showing -0 instead of just 0.  Is there a way to make it show as 0?

```
select to_char(-0.09,'9,999,999,999,999,990') from dual;
```

Comment: but the value to convert can be either positive or negative, greater or less than 0, it can be any number

Answer (score 4):

TO_CHAR is just format the number, not to round it up. SO, use [ROUND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm#SQLRF00698) first and then format as you need.

```
 select to_char(round(-0.09),'9,999,999,999,999,990') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the decimals try the following solution.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(-0.09),'9,999,999,999,999,990') FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to round the values go with the solution which Noel has suggested. Ideally, rounding the value is logical than just removing the decimals.